# Filter expression in Sqldatasouce

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a sqldatasource where i have added  a simple filter expression just for testing

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [project_details]" 
                FilterExpression="id=33" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
                EnableCaching="True">
```

and a grid view in update panel which has datasource as sqldatasouce1 . but on executing this page grid view is showing all the result withour any filtering . please help me i am totally struck here

Comment: :: Datasource mode is already set to "Dataset"

Comment: Have you checked for typo's? Are you sure you are using the correct SqlDatasourceID? FilterExpression should work just fine.

Comment: yuo.i have checked like hundred time.

Comment: i tried doing the way that you told using "where" it is working fine .but there is also one problem if i dont give a parameter value to the Parameter .it is not showing any result.because the user is suppose to add where parameter at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id is stored in text format then you might want to give single quotes in the expression as shown here:

id='33'

Comment: not working .i think single qoute is for string field only.MSDN You can include parameters in the FilterExpression property. If the parameter is a string or character type, enclose the parameter in single quotation marks. Quotation marks are not required, if the parameter is a numeric type. The FilterParameters collection contains the parameters that are evaluated for the placeholders that are found in the FilterExpression property.

Comment: That's why I wrote "If"...I didnt know what format your field was in and I gave you a sample solution in case it was string.