# FIlter expression not working Sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

This is my sqldatasource with filter expression

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [title], [client], [projectmanager], [project_scope], [project_materials], [project_gating], [project_cavities], [project_file], [project_otherdetails], [priority], [commodity], [status], [start_date], [end_date] FROM [project_details]" 
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
                    EnableCaching="True" CacheDuration="1000" 
FilterExpression="title= '{2}'">



 <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="mainsearch" 
                        PropertyName="SelectedItem.Value" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="start_date" 
                        PropertyName="Text" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" Name="end_date" 
                        PropertyName="Text" />
    <asp:ControlParameter   

                                  </FilterParameters>



    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

when i enter the value in Textbox2 it is not working what might be the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter expression in Sqldatasouce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595495/filter-expression-in-sqldatasouce)

Comment: Please don't ask the same questions again. Edit your first question.

Comment: sorrry will do in future.do you have any solution for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set the `ControlID="TextBox1"` in your SQL DataSource `SelectParameters`, but you are setting the value in `Textbox2`. You have to change it to `<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2"`

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="%" Name="title" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
```

**Edit:** Following your comments, you want to clear the `Where Clause`. You can do like...

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear(); // First Clear the Selected parameters
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [id], [title], [client], [projectmanager], [project_scope], [project_materials], [project_gating], [project_cavities], [project_file], [project_otherdetails], [priority], [commodity], [status], [start_date], [end_date] FROM [project_details]";
}
```

Comment: select parameter is not related to filter parameter .the select parameter is for where statement

Comment: I am talking for where statement.

Comment: but my question is about filter expression .remove the where statement from the code.after that it also not working .

Comment: You want to remove filteration expression or Where Clause from your query ?

Comment: filter expression sucks now i am working with where clause to solve the problem